# Как подключать другие пакеты в heroku golang

Tags: golang, heroku

как правильно следует импортировать другие пакеты в heroku? такие варианты не работают:

```
import "./routes"
import "github.com/dev/myApp/routes"
```

Comment: Ответ, как обычно, [в документации](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-go#manage-dependencies).

Comment: свою папку routes добавляю в папку vendor, в Godeps/Gideps.json добавил "Packages": [
        "./..."
    ],  выполнил godep save ./..., выдает: godep: Package (routes) not found

Comment: или там все свои функции надо определять именно в main.go? а хотел модульности

Comment: Для Godeps надо ключ `Deps` заполнить.

Comment: и где брать этот ключ?

Comment: Составить по образцу в документации. Там приведён пример для `gin`.

Comment: там сказано выполнить эту команду godep save ./..., чтобы сгенерировать, у меня  выводит: godep: Package (routes) not found

Comment: Потому что вы пропустили первый шаг -- заполнить список зависимостей в файле `Godeps.json`. Видимо, нужно уточнить, что выполнять инструкции надо **по порядку**. Если у вас проблемы с Godeps, то хотя бы приведите, что у вас в соответствующем файле.

Comment: у меня там заполнены тремя зависимостями: inject, martini и mysql. свойства Comment и Rev не понятно, откуда берутся

Comment: {
 "ImportPath": "github.com/saidoff/heroku-test",
 "GoVersion": "go1.8",
 "GodepVersion": "v79",
 "Packages": [
        "./..."
    ],
 "Deps": [
  {
   "ImportPath": "github.com/codegangsta/inject",
   "Comment": "v1.0-rc1-10-g33e0aa1",
   "Rev": "ключ"
  },
  {
   "ImportPath": "github.com/go-martini/martini",
   "Comment": "v1.0-188-g22fa469",
   "Rev": "ключ"
  },
  {
   "ImportPath": "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql",
   "Comment": "v1.3-2-g2e00b5c",
   "Rev": "ключ"
  }
 ]
}

Comment: Детали о вопросе в вопрос, пожалуйста.

Comment: непонятно такое подключение файлов. А если вместо godeps буду использовать что-нибудь другое, то там такая же ситуация будет?

Comment: Heroku использует Godeps, его дефолтный билдпак (buildpack) для Go во всяком случае. Есть, конечно, "лобовой" способ, засандалить зависимости в репозиторий -- надеюсь, не надо объяснять, почему это плохая идея. Можно ещё поискать другой билдпак, или даже сделать самому.

Comment: может быть, у Вас есть какие-нибудь проекты (образцы), где производится подключение своих пакетов? в инете не нашел, искал 2 часа

Comment: Нет, но можно попробовать следовать инструкциям к самому Godep, раз уж Heroku пользуется именно им. Кстати, [согласно им я неправ](https://github.com/tools/godep#how-to-use-godep-with-a-new-project), `godep save` действительно должен собрать пакеты по импортам сам.

Comment: ок, спасибо, тогда буду продолжать поиски нужного решения